# Inserting data from Java GUI text field to MS SQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, database, user-interface

I am trying and failing to send data from my java gui to my MS SQL database, I have dabbled with Java in the past but by no means am I an expert, I have been sourcing help from online and I have managed to connect my database to my application but i seem to be struggling with transferring data from the text fields to the database. (I am also new to stack so please put me straight in my place if I am out of line)

I have a class for my UI and a class for the database connection, the code is from a online resource and it seems straight forward and logical to follow (in my eyes) but I cannot seem to crack what should be a simple problem. The process is get the text from the text field and insert using a statement in to the SQL database, I can send data from within my code easily but I would ideally like it from the text fields.

The code cannot seem to see the "Connection" - error = java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Connection

I apologise in advance if this is a very simple mistake but it is driving me insane as it should be a fairly straight forward process. In plain terms it should be able to fill out the four text fields which fill the four columns in my DB when the submit button is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the code for the action on my button:

```
private void SubmitBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
String name = Name.getText();
String number = Number.getText();
String title = Title.getText();
String year = Year.getText();
String query = "insert into students values ('"+Name+"','"+Number+"','"+Title+"','"Year+"')";
System.out.println(query);


    try {
    Connection c = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

this is the code in my database class

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

static private Connection  connection;

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
    if(connection == null){
        //JDBC
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=*******;user=****;password=******;");
    }
    return connection;
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Don't paste code as images.

Comment: Apologies - my mistake

Comment: Did you import all necessary classes? Such as `java.sql.Connection`?

Comment: This in not directly related to your question, but you shouldn't assemble your query by concatenating with a string from UI. This way, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Use `PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("insert into students values (?, ?, ?, ?)"); stmt.setString(1, name); stmt.setString(2, number); stmt.setString(3, title); stmt.setString(4, year);` instead.